# Ionic2: updating to beta 5 and 6

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm having some problems to update Ionic2 version from beta 4 to 5/6.

With beta 4 the look and feel in browser was iOS-like by default. In 5 and 6, the style is Android-like and I have multiple rendering problems when I navigate through pages (z-index).
The tutorial of beta 6 it shows Android-like too on browser.

The browser is Chrome (last version) on Mac OS (last version)

In iOS simulator everything is ok.

Do you know what it's the problem?

I did everything of this guide: [GUIDE](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-projects-updating-to-beta-6/50049)

package.json

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "ionic-native": "^1.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.4",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "3.4.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "name": "",
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  When viewed on the web, Ionic defaults to Material Design.  Note: This is accurate as of May 2nd, 2016.  This could potentially change in the future.

If you wish to view the app in a different style for testing, you can set a query parameter such as:

```
localhost:8100/index.html?ionicplatform=ios
```

The theme/configuration can also be overriden to show a different platform's styling.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/

Comment: Thanks! the problem it's the md-transition config. With ios-transition it's ok.